# How to update boosts symbolic links all at once?

Tags: boost, symlink

I have boost 1.58.0 and 1.67.0 libraries under /usr/lib and my libboost_*.so is pointing to the 1.67 lib. Now I would like to change all the symbolic links at once with a command like this `ln -f libboost_*.so.1.58.0 libboost_*.so`.

My actual question is how do I make the first star remember so that the second star has the same name? Excuse me for the lack of jargon, I'm not sure how to phrase this better.

Is there an easy solution for this or would I have to write a shellscript saving the first match into some intermediate variable?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small python script. Would still be interesting to see if there is a better shell solution.

```
import os

dir = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
files = os.listdir(dir)
print(files)

for file in files:
    if False or os.path.islink(os.path.join(dir, file)):
        if "boost" in file:
            print("Creating symlink for file " + file)
            src = os.path.join(dir, file + ".1.58.0")
            dst = os.path.join(dir, file)
            print(src)
            print(dst)
            try:
                os.symlink(src, dst)
            except OSError:
                os.remove(dst)
                os.symlink(src, dst)
```